# Series simplification in Maxima

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

I try

```
sum(k, k, 1, n+1)-sum(k, k, 1, n),simpsum;
```

Why does it give `n+1`?

```
collect(sum(k, k, 1, n+1)-sum(k, k, 1, n));
```

neither?

Comment: After `sum(...) ...`, try `ratsimp(%)` or `expand(%)` -- does that yield the expected result? See also `simplify_sum`, which knows the same identities as `simpsum` and a lot more. Try `load("simplify_sum")` and then `simplify_sum(<your summation expression here>)`.

Comment: sum(k, k, 1, n+1)-sum(k, k, 1, n),simpsum;ratsimp(%); gives the correct result n+1. Thank you  
@Robert Dodier

Comment: sum(k, k, 1, n+1)-sum(k, k, 1, n),simpsum;expand(%); too !

Comment: load("simplify_sum");simplify_sum(sum(k, k, 1, n+1)-sum(k, k, 1, n)); fails

Comment: When you say simplify_sum fails, I guess you just mean that it doesn't give the simplest form and you have to apply `expand` or `ratsimp`. Well, just getting to an expression in `n` without the summations is the hard part of the problem, so I think the additional simplification is not a big deal. My main point about simplify_sum is that it applies many summation identities that simpsum doesn't know about.